# Reading Matrix Market Graphs in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

is there any possibility to read MatrixMarket (*.mtx) graphs using the python igraph framework?
http://networkrepository.com/ provides a huge set of different test networks, which would be helpful in case igraph could read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found a solution.
The graphs provided at http://networkrepository.com/ are in edgelist format.
Removing trailing 2 lines (a line of comments and a line of summary about the graph) leaves a normal edgelist file, which can be read with

```
import igraph
g = igraph.read("filename.mtx", format="edge")
```